# Have some trouble proving $(1-x)^n \geq 1-nx$

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, proof-verification, induction

Here is the question: Prove that $(1-x)^n \geq 1-nx,~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}~and~x\in(0,1)$.

My proof by induction:
Base Case: when $n=1$, $(1-x)^1\geq 1-1\cdot x$
Induction Hypothesis: $\forall i \in [1,k],~(1-x)^i\geq 1-ix$
Inductive Steps: $(1-x)^{k+1}=(1-x)^k(1-x)\geq (1-kx)(1-x)=1-(k+1)x+kx^2>1-(k+1)x$

However, by this reasoning, I have only shown that $(1-x)^{k+1}>1-(k+1)x$ and have never shown that the equality.
Then I tried an alternative to show that, when $n=1$, the equality holds and then prove that the inequality holds for every natural number $n\geq2$. But I am not sure that the alternative reasoning is valid.

I know similar question has been posted before but in this one, $0<x<1$, so I cannot just reason that $1-(k+1)x+kx^2\geq 1-(k+1)x$.

Many thanks,
D.

Comment: $a>b \implies a \ge b$. In particular, $(1-x)^{k+1} > 1-(k+1)x \implies (1-x)^{k+1} \ge 1-(k+1)x$ and you are done.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Equality can only hold when $k=0$, when the $kx^2$ contributes nothing. This can be seen directly from your proof. The last inequality should be $\geq$ to account for the $k=0$ case.

Comment: However, there exists a condition such that $k\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$. Hence the case where $k=0$ does not exist. (In this question, we assume natural number excludes 0)

Comment: @Dean if $\mathbb N$ contains 0 by your definition, then your base case should not be $n=1$. Note it still holds if $n=0$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant that in this question, we do not consider $0\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence the reasoning for any assumption that $k=0$ does not hold. That's why I mentioned that $k\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: @Dean then equality only holds in the base case and your proof is fine. What exactly is the problem you're having? You're finished.

Comment: That's the thing, the equality only holds in base case. So when I use $k+1$, I can only get $(1-x)^k+1\geq1-(k+1)x+kx^2\gneq 1- (k+1)x$

Comment: Actually, I think I got it. Thanks

Comment: @Dean that's not a problem. If $a>b$, then $a\geq b$. You can just replace it with $\geq$ instead if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have totally got it now

Comment: @Dean no problem.